# nginx pass rewritten URL to web server

Tags: nginx

I'm new to nginx, and I'd like to know if there is a way to pass an edited request URL to a web server.  For example, I may have a web server running (Let's say apache.  Or Flask.).  I want all requests to /foo/(.*)$ to go to my web server, but I want my web server to see them without the foo.  But if the initial request didn't have the foo, it would go somewhere else completely.

A request to /foo/bar would be routed to my web server, which would see the request simply as "/bar".  However, a request that originally was made to "/bar" would be handled differently entirely.  (So I don't just want to redirect).

Is there any way to do this?  My thinking is that I could use this to modularize and namespace applications I write, where I could write an application as if it were routing requests on root, but it would actually be buried deeper in my site.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick **(untested)**:

```
location /foo {
    rewrite /[^/](/.*) $1 break;
    # Pass to web server, e.g.:
    #proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

Note that the regular expression within the rewrite will strip any sub-directory from the request; but only **one** sub-directory. You could also use:

```
rewrite /foo(/.*) $1 break;
```

Which is more readable and clearer but not as powerful. This is up to you and your regular expression skills.